# Compress and uncompress using different version of snappy-java library

Tags: compression, snappy

Can using different version of xerial cause compression error and could be not backward compatible?

I am compressing using:

```
            org = "org.xerial.snappy",
            name = "snappy-java",
            rev = "1.1.7.3",
```

and uncompressing using:

```
            org = "org.xerial.snappy",
            name = "snappy-java",
            rev = "1.0.3.2",
```

And getting following error:

```
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:98)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawUncompress(Snappy.java:474)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:513)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readFully(SnappyInputStream.java:147)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readHeader(SnappyInputStream.java:99)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.<init>(SnappyInputStream.java:59)
    at com.twitter.ads.common.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.deserialize(SnappyCompressionCodec.java:85)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code used to compress? If so, there's a "compatibility matrix" you can reference to see how to uncompress data depending on which method was used to write it: https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java#compatibility-notes